# Visual Studio lower cases content within tags when you paste something

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I try to paste some C# code in .cshtml view, visual studio 2013 lower cases content within statements like this:

```
List<MyModel>
```

So as a result I see this

```
List<mymodel>
```

Which is not correct. Do you have any ideas why? Btw, I have Resharper installed.

Comment: I really doubt VS (by the way, you haven't specified your VS version) itself does it. Probably you have some addon installed and this behaviour caused by this addon.

Comment: start VS in safe mode and see if you can repro.  If not, then it's an extension doing it.

Comment: Actually, I've seen this happen many times before. It is VS, but it only happens when the code is jacked such that Intellisense can't parse it properly. It's interpreting the `<MyModel>` bit as an HTML tag, and then lowercasing it as it does all HTML tags as a result.

Comment: I have the same error and I can reproduce that in safe mode, so for me it isn't extension, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess: You have "Normalize tag names" enabled in ReSharper. To check, go to Visual Studio's Tools menu > Options > Resharper > Options button > Code Editing section > HTML > Code Style > Normalize tag names. Having that enabled will force lower-case on HTML tags (which your List type is maybe detected as, being between angle brackets).

If that's not it, I'd poke around for similar settings in ReSharper.

[image: ReSharper Ultimate options]
*Shown: Options dialog for ReSharper Ultimate in VS 2015. YMMV.*

Answer (score 1):

Bah. I broke my own rule and posted an answer as a comment. So, here it is as an answer.

This happens when the code is jacked and Intellisense can't properly parse it. The `<MyModel>` bit is being interpreted as an HTML tag, rather than as C# code, and by style conventions, VS lowercases all HTML tags.

Long and short, to prevent it, make sure that both the code you're copying and pasting and the code your pasting it into are valid Razor code. You can also do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> immediately after the paste. When VS does automatic formatting on a block of code, the first undo in the stack is its formatting.